# WS2815 circuit erratic behaviour

Tags: rgb, ws2812b

I have been having problems driving WS2812 LEDs; the radiated emissions were too high to pass UK tests. See [Radiated emissions from WS2812 LEDs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660535/radiated-emissions-from-ws2812-leds)
I finally bit the bullet and went for LEDs on a printed PCB. I used 12v WS2815E LEDs, in a 7x7 pattern on a single layer aluminium board. Lots of ground plane, lots of decoupling. I used decoupling after each LED, as was suggested by an EMC tester.

[image]

And the PCB layout:
[image]

It kind of works a bit unless I drive the brightness up past 15%. The it goes into fitting mode, with random flashes of random colours. Can anyone comment on the schematic, and suggest why it acts so erratically? Someone has suggested that the 470 resistors on VDD may be starving the LEDs, leading them to reset constantly. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, since someone suggested what it could be, did you verify if the suggestion was true or false?

Comment: 470R-100p pair has a cut-off frequency of ~3.4 MHz which corresponds to ~300 ns. Given the times for T0 and T1 (e.g. 220~380 ns for T0H), this RC filter apparently chops off the edges or even the pulses. Have you tried without the filter on the Dx lines?

Comment: The question mentions both WS2812 and WS2815E LEDs. Which device is it, and do you have a link to an datasheet for the device? On a quick search could only find a Chinese datasheet for the WS2815E.

Comment: Did you scope out the VDD pin during the problem behavior? The 470 ohm resistors on the VDD lines do seem excessive. Recognize that for just a 15mA current draw the resistor causes a drop of 7.05V on the LED's VDD pin, (that drops VDD to 4.95V), and you likely draw more current than that. You might consider reducing the resistor to about 120 ohms and increasing the filter cap to 0.1uF, or even replacing the resistor with a chip ferrite of a few turns. Ideally you should monitor the VDD line with a scope to verify you are getting a good compromise of filtering verses voltage drop.

Comment: why do you have caps on the data line? I would think that wouldn't work at all. you also don't need a resistor in each data line, only the first, the DO i/v levels are regulated on-chip to work perfect to the next DIN with "0" ohms.

Comment: What Nedd says needs noting :-). (I'd expect the low pss filtering of the data to be very marginal).